# Sql Query Over Database Link Returns Malformed rowid

Tags: oracle

A query I am attempting to run is returning a malformed `rowid`. This query is over a public database link between a test org and a production org.

Rather than returning in the standard format, it returns malformed data.

Example:
instead of returning something like `AAO9vQBAaABLNDbAAI` it returns `AAP9vOBAaAALMo/AAW`.

This is the query:

```
select rowid from tind@prod4.esz.college.edu where tind_DOC_CODE ||
    tind_SEQ_NUM ||
    tind_ITEM_NUM ||
    tind_SUBMISSION_NUMBER ||
    tind_LEDGER_IND ||
    tind_FIELD_CODE = 'I0906447100G02';
```

I was wondering if anyone was familiar with this sort of behavior, and it is possible to fix it so that returns a valid `rowid`?

Comment: Why do you think it's malformed ? Please see e.g. [Rowid Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50998): _"Rowids are stored as base 64 values that can contain the characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and the plus sign (+) and forward slash (/)."_.

Comment: The main reason I thought they were malformed was because attempting to use it as a rowid caused a invalid row id error.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is malformed?

Extended rowids are stored as base 64 values that can contain the characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and the plus sign (+) and forward slash (/). Extended rowids are not available directly. You can use a supplied package, DBMS_ROWID, to interpret extended rowid contents. The package functions extract and provide information that would be available directly from a restricted rowid as well as information specific to extended rowids.

Edit:  A quick check of my own db shows many / and + symbols in the rowids.